# Telegram bot response issue (updating…)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm developing a Telegram bot and facing intermittent delays of 1-2 seconds sometimes,
[image: Updating status]
marked by an "updating" status, during interactions. Despite utilizing the Telegram Python bot library alongside aniogram and experimenting with both polling and webhooks (standalone and within libraries), the issue persists. What strategies can I employ to eliminate these response delays?

I tried to use various libraries of telegram and changing server without any luck